# Stream Video to website

Tags: php, video, streaming, video-streaming, live-streaming

We have been given a request to provide a live feed of our meetings on our website. Our web site uses PHP. I am thinking of getting an IP camera in the meeting room and somehow relay the video to the website. The video also needs to be saved for archiving.

Can you guys provide some recommendations on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can stream a cam to a website via multiple ways.

1. use Windows media Server/ Flash media Server. Push your webcam to the server by Windows Media Encoder or flash media encoder, and use the server live link to link with your website via any suitable player (like jwplayer).Windows media Server/ Flash media Server do have the ability to archive the video streams.
2. Use Windows Media Encoder to stream your webcam to anyone without a server involved. when your encoder starts, you will get a URL to view your stream, which you can use to publish in your site.
3. use third party streaming services, where they give you a publishing point to publish your webcam stream, and use the link provided by them to show it on your website. (check with brighcove or Mogulus by LiveStream

Hope this helps.